# Unit testing kernel drivers

Tags: windows, unit-testing, kernel, drivers

I'm looking for a testing framework for the Windows kernel environment. So far, I've found [cfix](http://cfix.sourceforge.net/). Has any one tried it? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being the author of cfix, I might be a little biased here -- but as a matter of fact, I am currently not aware of any other unit-testing framework for NT kernel mode.

If you should experience any problems with cfix, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Static Driver Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/tools/SDV.mspx) is described as "a compile-time tool that explores code paths in a device driver by symbolically executing the source code. SDV is a unit-testing tool for Microsoft Windows device drivers based on the Windows Driver Model (WDM)."

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm aware of SDV, but I'm interested in a unit testing framework, not a static analysis tool.

Comment: Hmmm. Why does MS then describe SDV as "a unit-testing tool for MS device drivers..."? Bad description? Misuse of the phrase "unit testing"?

Comment: Probably a bad choice of words. In any case, regardless of its function, SDV imposes too many restrictions (no C++, etc...)